# Prove that $\Phi $ increasing : $\Phi (n)=(nq_{n})^{2}+2np_{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, functions

I have a difficult problem for me!

Problem :

Let  $q_{n}\in\mathbb{N^{*}}$ and $p_{n}\in\mathbb{N}$ be two sequence

Defined application following :

$$\Phi (n) : \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$$

$$\Phi (n)=(nq_{n})^{2}+2np_{n}$$

Question :

Prove that $\Phi $ are $\operatorname{increasing}$ ?

My note :

I always see increasing in $\mathbb{R}$ so I'm shocked what I will use!

I don't have any ideas to starte in this problem

I have already see your solution

Comment: "Eventually" increasing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason for $\Phi$ to be increasing in general.

For instance take 
$$
q_n=\begin{cases} n,&\ n\text{ even}\\ 1,&\ n\text{ odd} \end{cases}
$$
and $p_n=0$ for all $n$. Then $\Phi $ takes the values 
$$
1, 16, 9, 256, 25, \ldots, (2k)^4, (2k+1)^2,\ldots
$$
so it is never monotone over three consecutive $n$.

Comment: thanks sir 